# Insert an empty column in IBM (Telelogic) DOORS

Tags: requirements, ibm-doors

As a reviewer, I've to add an empty REVIEW column in a DOORS module. Actually I can add columns easily but they're associated to other attributes and there is no "emtpty" option to choose.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure you want to add content to the column as a result of your review, like "OK" or "not OK".
Content is stored in attributes. So, you first have to add a new *attribute* on object level to the module with the desired data type (like predefined values, boolean, string or text), and then add a *column* to your review view which shows the new attribute.